# Controller é executado toda a vez que mudo de rota

Tags: angularjs

No index.html tenho 2 views:

- sidebar-left : onde o menu é carregado após o login.
- content :  onde a página em questão é carregada

Estou utilizando angular-ui-router e após o login, o utilizador é redirecionado para a dashboard.

Na dashboard é feito o carregamento da sidebar-left:

```
.state('dashboard', {
            url: "/dashboard",               
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'view/dashboard.html',
                    resolve: {
                        auth : function ($q, Session) {
                            var userInfo = Session.getUserInfo();
                            if (userInfo) return $q.when(userInfo);
                            else return $q.reject({ authenticated: false });
                        }
                    },
                    controller: 'dashboard'
                },
                'sidebar-left' : { templateUrl: 'view/sidebar-left.html', controller: 'menu' }
            },
        })
```

Acontece que a sidebar-left é comum em todas as páginas, ao mudar da dashboard para outra área a sidebar desaparece.

Isso eu resolvi adicionando em todas as rotas a view "sidebar-left".

Acontece que a view "sidebar-left" está associada a um controller que faz um GET ao servidor e o PHP faz a leitura da base de dados e retorna o menu.

Toda vez que mudo a rota, esse controller é executado fazendo um GET desnecessário ao servidor.

O problema é a lógica utilizada, como faço para que o menu seja carregado apenas uma única vez?

Answer (score 1):

Realmente do jeito que foi implementado cada vez que o estado 'dashboard' for acionado os dois controllers serão criados novamente.

Se a sua ideia é deixar o 'sidebar-left' sempre presente, você pode usar o conteito de hierarquia de estados do ui-router, veja a seguinte pagina: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Especificamente no seu caso, algo parecido com isto:

```
state('root', {
   abstract: true,
   templateUrl: 'view/sidebar-left.html',
   controller: 'menu'
}).state('dashboard', {
   url: "/dashboard",
   parent: 'root',
   views: {
      'content': {
         templateUrl: 'view/dashboard.html',
         resolve: {
            auth: function ($q, Session) {
               var userInfo = Session.getUserInfo();
               if (userInfo) return $q.when(userInfo);
               else return $q.reject({ authenticated: false });
            }
         },
         controller: 'dashboard'
      }
   },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenho usado uma implementação diferente, usando o **ng-include** e o **ng-view**,
vejo muito ela sendo usada nesses templates de admin feitos em angularjs.

Exemplo:

```html
<body ng-app="app">
  <!-- #Aqui é o header-->
  <section ng-include=" 'views/header.html' "
           class="header-container "
           ng-controller="HeaderCtrl"></section>

  <div class="main-container">
      <!-- #Aqui é o menu-->
      <aside ng-include=" 'views/nav.html' " class="nav-container"></aside>

      <!-- #Aqui é o conteudo vindo das rotas do angularjs-->
      <div id="content" class="content-container">
          <section ng-view></section>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```